# Keep Computer Awake During Long Running

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel VBA/Macro that will likely take 20 hours to run. However the computer keeps sleeping and then locking if I don't stay at the computer. How can I keep the computer awake or alive while my VBA runs?
I tried adding code to move the mouse around and send mouse clicks. I even tired having a live YouTube stream up.

Comment: This is in your powerplan of windows and has nothing to do with excel. type powerplan in search ond of you go.

Comment: I should have mentioned this is a company PC and the IT team has limited what can br changed. Despite that, had already changed the plan and it still doesn't matter.

Comment: Used to run macros across 2 days - cpu was 60MHz then... But screensaver would come on and the desktop continued fine. Also used to run CFD jobs that took 40 days but we used SGI machines for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A program uses `SetThreadExecutionState` to ask Windows to not sleep.

> **SetThreadExecutionState**
>
> Enables an application to inform the system that it is in use, thereby
> preventing the system from entering sleep or turning off the display
> while the application is running.
>
> The system automatically detects activities such as local keyboard or
> mouse input, server activity, and changing window focus. Activities
> that are not automatically detected include disk or CPU activity and
> video display.
>
> Calling SetThreadExecutionState without ES_CONTINUOUS simply resets
> the idle timer; to keep the display or system in the working state,
> the thread must call SetThreadExecutionState periodically.
>
> To run properly on a power-managed computer, applications such as fax
> servers, answering machines, backup agents, and network management
> applications must use both ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED and ES_CONTINUOUS when
> they process events. Multimedia applications, such as video players
> and presentation applications, must use ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED when they
> display video for long periods of time without user input.
> Applications such as word processors, spreadsheets, browsers, and
> games do not need to call SetThreadExecutionState.

You just call it and it applies to the calling thread.

```
Public Declare Function SetThreadExecutionState Lib "Kernel32" (ByVal esFlags as Long) as Long
Public Const  ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED = &h40
Public Const  ES_CONTINUOUS = &h80000000
Public Const  ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = &h2
Public Const  ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = &h1
Public Const  ES_USER_PRESENT = &h4

  Dim Ret as Long
  'System on monitor off
  Ret = SetThreadExecutionState(ES_Continuous + ES_System_Required + ES_Awaymode_Required)

  'System and monitor on
  Ret = SetThreadExecutionState(ES_Continuous + ES_Display_Required + ES_Awaymode_Required)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate

From my website https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2020/05/keepdisplayon-runs-program-preventing.html