# How to simulate keyboard press in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

How can one simulate keyboard press using Word VBA so that my machine does not go into idle state and get locked.

The above can be realized in Python, as follows:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Controller
import time

keyboard = Controller()

while True:
    keyboard.type("Hello World")
    keyboard.press('\n')
    time.sleep(60)
```

I was wondering if you could help me figure a way to do this using Word VBA. I could only get to the following state (the code works, but i don't think it simulates a keyboard press); the machine goes into the idle state and gets locked:

```
Dim interval As Date

Sub ScheduleNextPrint()
    Application.OnTime When:=interval, Name:="StartPrinting"
End Sub

Sub StartPrinting()
    interval = Now + TimeValue("00:01:00")
    PrintHelloWorld ' Initial call to display "Hello, World!"
    ScheduleNextPrint
End Sub

Sub PrintHelloWorld()
    Dim doc As Document
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    
    doc.Range.InsertAfter "Hello, World!"
    doc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74763306/keep-computer-awake-during-long-running

Comment: You can send virtual keystrokes with [`Application.SendKeys()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sendkeys-statement), although it's typically frowned upon.